# Convert Excel array formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, array-formulas

I'm trying to do "vlookup" with 2 different criteria(Column A and G values) using "Index" and "Match" functions.

and here is the line i used for the Excel command.

```
=INDEX(Database!A:KG,MATCH(1,(Database!A:A='TempSheet'!A2)*(Database!G:G='TempSheet'!G2),0),10)
```

How would I do it with VBA? It's keep giving me the error message "Compile error: Expected end of statement".

```
Selection= _
    "=Index(DB.Range("A:KG"), Match(1, (DB.Range("A" = Temp.Range("A" & i).Value)) * (DB.Range("G" = Temp.Range("G" & i).Value)), 0), 10)"
```

Thanks

Comment: What about `"=INDEX(Database!A:KG,MATCH(1,(Database!A:A='TempSheet'!A2)*(Database!G:G='TempSheet'!G2),0),10)"`?

Comment: Please show your actual code in the question, formatted with the code viewer.

Comment: You need to escape the double-quotes inside a literal string... Also, you can't use Variable names like `DB` inside a literal string.

Comment: If you cannot get a complicated expression to work, try building up to it using smaller components of the expression. For instance, try getting the `Match` expression to work, followed by `Index` - separately. You need to use either `Application.Worksheetfunction.` or `Evaluate` - and you can check the syntax here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx (with example).

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use a spreadsheet formula inside a VBA code, you need to precede it with <*Excel.WorksheetFunction.*> or <*Application.WorksheetFunction.*>.

For example:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`

instead of Match only.

Answer (score 0):

I have had little luck getting array formulas to work correctly via VBA, and use the 'IFERROR' as a workaround like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Database!A:Z,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B1, Database!A:Z,1,FALSE))
```

This function will attempt to match A1, and in case of a #VALUE error, it will match B1.

To get this kind of formula populated on a sheet in VBA, you can loop down your sheet using the '.formula' approach.

```
' get length of source data
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' now starting from row 2 to preserve headings
For i = 2 To RowCount
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(""ISO"",V" & i & ")),""Order type not supported"",""Transit"")"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, 6).Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXT(VLOOKUP(B" & i & ",Database!A:N,7,FALSE),""dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM AM/PM""),"""")"
Next
```

Not exactly what you were after, but hope it helps!